# to find the $x$th element in a series like $a_1,a_1,a_2,a_1,a_2,a_3,a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

we have say n numbers

```
                                      a1 ,a2,a3,.......aN .
```

let us say that n=5 so numbers are

```
                           a1 ,a2,a3,a4,a5
```

so we form a sequence like this

```
                        a1,a1,a2,a1,a2,a3,a1,a2,a3,a4,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5
```

what is a  general formula to know the term at say xth position .If x=5 in above SEQUENCE we print a2  ,if x=9 , we print  a3

[image]

Comment: You mean $a_1=1$, $a_2=1$, $a_3=2$, $a_4=1$, $a_5=2$ ...

Comment: @no these are numbers a1 a1 a2 a1 a2 a3 a1 a2 a3 a4 not a1=1

Comment: $a$ means a sequence. $a_1$ means the first number in the sequence.

Comment: @KennyLau look at the image now for better undewrstanding of question

Comment: $a_k$ where $k = x -\frac12\left\lfloor \frac{\sqrt{8x-7}-1}{2} \right\rfloor
\left(\left\lfloor \frac{\sqrt{8x-7}-1}{2} \right\rfloor + 1\right)
$ I think I've seen this question recently....

Comment: @achillehui yes this was asked in codeforces div 2b yesterday

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind this formula: $$1+2+\cdots+n\equiv\frac{n(n+1)}2$$

Now, let us put your sequence in groups:

```
(a1), (a1,a2), (a1,a2,a3), (a1,a2,a3,a4), (a1,a2,a3,a4,a5)
```

Notice that the $n$-th block starts at $x=1+2+\cdots+(n-1)+1=\dfrac{(n-1)n}2+1$.

For example:

- The $1$st block starts at $x=\dfrac{0\times1}2+1=1$
- The $2$nd block starts at $x=\dfrac{1\times2}2+1=2$
- The $3$rd block starts at $x=\dfrac{2\times3}2+1=4$
- The $4$th block starts at $x=\dfrac{3\times4}2+1=7$

Now, this is actually [A000124](http://oeis.org/A000124).

---

For your question, we find the previous starting place.

For example, when $x=5$, the closest starting place behind it is $x=4$, which is the start of the third block.

Then, we can find that we should print `a2`.

Comment: please modimy your answer now

Comment: @satya What is wrong with my answer?

Comment: The first equality dosent use an equality symbol.

Comment: @N.S.JOHN That is an equivalent symbol, meaning that it is an identity (always equal) instead of an equation.

Comment: I thought it was only for modular calculations. Sorry

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_bar#Mathematics_and_philosophy).

Answer (score 0):

Consider triangular numbers and their place in this problem. Your sequence makes a pattern like this:

```
           a1
        a1   a2
     a1   a2   a3
  a1   a2   a3   a4
```

a1   a2   a3   a4   a5

Instead of finding the value of *x* mod (a number), find *x* mod (the triangular number less than or equal to *x*).

Triangular numbers are the number of elements in a triangular array. The sequence of triangular numbers is 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, ...

Triangular numbers can also be a function, where $T(1)=1, T(2)=3, T(3)=6,...$ etc.

If $x=9$, the triangular number less than 9 is 6. So 9 mod (6) = 3 and we print a3. If $x=28$, which is a triangular number, we need to find $T(n)=28.$ In this case, $n=7$, so we print a7.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the first appearance of the  term   $a_n$ occurs at $(1+2 + \cdots n) =\frac{n(n+1)}{2} $th position. 
Now let us create an **algorithm** to find the **xth** term

$\bullet$ If $x$ is a triangular number then its done ,i.e. if $x=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ then $a_x =a_n$

$\bullet$Let $x$ lies between $\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$ and $\frac{(k+1)(k+2)}{2}$,i.e, $\frac{k(k+1)}{2} <x  < \frac{(k+1)(k+2)}{2}$. This suggests that the $xth$ term has crossed all $(a_i)_{i\le k}$ atleast once.

$\bullet$ Define $m=x-\frac{k(k+1)}{2}, \ m=1,2,...k$. Then the $a_x=a_m$. Done!

Answer (score 0):

Let $T_n$ denote the triangular number $T_n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.  Note that $a_n$ first appears at position $T_n$.  The sequence of numbers at positions $T_{n}+1, \dots, T_{n+1}$ is $a_1, \dots a_{n+1}$.  Consequently, given a position, we need to know which two triangular numbers it is between and haw far along the gap between them it is.

First, given a position, $m$, we wish to know $n$ such that \begin{align}
    T_n <{} &m \leq T_{n+1}  \\
    \frac{n(n+1)}{2} <{} &m \leq \frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}  \\
    n(n+1) <{} 2&m \leq (n+1)(n+2)  \\
    \frac{-3 + \sqrt{8m+1}}{2} \leq{} &n < \frac{-1 + \sqrt{8m+1}}{2}  \text{.}
\end{align}
We can take the ceiling on the left to get an integer for $n$.  Call this $\hat{n} = \left\lceil \frac{-3 + \sqrt{8m+1}}{2} \right\rceil$.  Then you have $a_{m-T_{\hat{n}}}$ at the $m^\text{th}$ position your list.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complete solution: Consider the function $d(m) = m(m+1)/2$ that assigns each number $n$ the $n$-th corresponding triangle number. We have an ascending real-valued left inverse

$$d^{-1}(n) = \frac{\sqrt{8n+1}-1}{2}.$$

We want to find a $f(n)$ such that $$f(1) = 1, f(2) = 1, f(3) = 2, f(4) = 1, f(5) = 2, f(6) = 3, f(7) = 1$$ and so on. Then the $n$-th element of your sequence is $a_{f(n)}$.

We know that $n-f(n)$ is a triangle number, namely the largest triangle number smaller than $n$, so $d^{-1}(n-f(n))$ is the largest integer smaller than $d^{-1}(n)$.

Hence we have $d^{-1}(n-f(n)) = \lceil d^{-1}(n)\rceil - 1$, which we can solve for $f(n)$ as

$$f(n) = n-d(\lceil d^{-1}(n) \rceil - 1) = n-\frac{1}{2}\left\lceil \frac{\sqrt{8n+1}-1}{2}\right\rceil \left\lceil \frac{\sqrt{8n+1}-3}{2}\right\rceil.$$

Your sequence is now $a_{f(1)}, a_{f(2)}, a_{f(3)}, a_{f(4)}, a_{f(5)}, \ldots$

Comment: can you prove your point illustrating it with an example

Comment: What do you mean, example? [Here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=n-1%2F2*ceil%28%28sqrt%288n%2B1%29-1%29%2F2%29*ceil%28%28sqrt%288n%2B1%29-3%29%2F2%29+for+n+%3D+1+to+100)'s a WolframAlpha input.

Answer (score 0):

By the triangular numbers, $a_1$ appears at indexes $T_m=\frac{m(m+1)}2$. For a given $n$, you need to find $m$ and the corresponding offset from $T_m$.

Then, $T_m=\frac{(m+\frac12)^2-\frac14}2$, so that by inverting

$$m=\lfloor\sqrt{2n+\frac14}-\frac12\rfloor,$$ and after transformation the requested index is

$$n-\frac12\left(\lfloor\frac{\sqrt{8n+1}-1}2\rfloor\right)\left(\lfloor\frac{\sqrt{8n+1}+1}2\rfloor\right)+1.$$

---

If you start at $n=1$,

$$n-\frac12\left(\lfloor\frac{\sqrt{8n-7}-1}2\rfloor\right)\left(\lfloor\frac{\sqrt{8n-7}+1}2\rfloor\right).$$